# Inner class calling

Tags: java, inner-classes

I've `class` `BubblesFrame` which has `inner class` `startnewGame` :

```
 public class startNewGame implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            remove(panel);
            panel = new BubbleMainPanel();
            add(panel);
            validate();
            panel.repaint();

        }
    }
```

in `class` `Menu` i'd like to add `event handler` `startNewGame`

```
 ActionListener listener = new BubblesFrame.startNewGame();
        newGame.addActionListener(listener);
```

but it returns following error:

> No enclosing instance of type BubblesFrame is accessible. Must
>   qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type 
>   BubblesFrame (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of BubblesFrame)

what's wrong with my inner class?

Comment: Please capitalize your class names.

Comment: That is because you forgot to instantiate your inner class with a new keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did instantiate your outer class, but you forgot to instantiate your inner class.

```
BubblesFrame f = new BubblesFrame();  //Instantiate outer class
ActionListener listener = f.new startNewGame(); //Instantiate inner class
```

I am more curious why would you want to expose your inner class when it is a `listener` for your BubblesFrame. You might want to look into your design pattern again.

Usually it is either an anonymous class or a private class.

Answer (score 1):

Make `startNewGame` class [static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your inner class is not static use this approach:

```
 ActionListener listener = new BubblesFrame().new startNewGame();
```

if `startNewGame` class is `static` you can do as you have done before:

```
ActionListener listener = new BubblesFrame.startNewGame();
```